# how does walk directory in multiple thread in java 6?

Tags: java, multithreading, directory, java-6

I have program which goes along  the directories with the help of multithreading. It takes a lot of time for threads to wait for each other.
I need to run this code  parallely and dicrease time of waiting between the threads.
 What collections should be used??

```
public class DirectoryWalker {
    static Queue<String> filesQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");

public static String fileInfo(File f) {
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
    String file = "file = ";
    String date = "date = ";
    String size = "size = ";
    str.append("[\n" + file + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\n" + date + dateFormat.format(f.lastModified()) + "\n" + size + f.length() + "]");
    return str.toString();
}

public static void walk(final Queue<File> directoriesQueue) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File mainDirectory = directoriesQueue.poll();
            if (mainDirectory.listFiles() != null) {
                File[] innerDirectory = mainDirectory.listFiles();
                System.out.println(directoriesQueue.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < innerDirectory.length; i++) {
                    if (innerDirectory[i].isDirectory()) {
                        directoriesQueue.add(innerDirectory[i]);
                    } else {
                        filesQueue.add(fileInfo(innerDirectory[i]));
                    }
                }
            }
            walk(directoriesQueue);
            if (directoriesQueue.size() == 0) {
                executor.shutdown();
            }

        }
    });

    executor.submit(thread);

}
```

Comment: There is no reason for your `thread` variable to be of type `Thread`, and there is no reason for the object that you assign to it to be a `Thread` object.  You should change the type to `Runnable`, and you should directly assign the `new Runnable() {...}` object to it.

Comment: Your disk has only 1 serial (ata) connection, threads can not actually read from disk in parallel.

Comment: Your code shuts down the `executor` as soon as any one task sees the queue empty.  But that's totally un-synchronized.  How does the task know that some other task is not just about to add more entries to the queue?